# The monotonicity of entropy operator

Tags: density-function, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information, cross-entropy

Define the entropy operator of a distribution as $\mathbb{H}(p) = -\int p \log p$, how does the entropy change for distributions that are proportional to the powers of $p$?

For example, define $\tilde{p} = \frac{\sqrt{p}}{\int \sqrt{p}}$, can we say anything about the relation between $\mathbb{H}(p)$ and $\mathbb{H}(\tilde{p})$? If such a general rule is impossible, what if we restrict $p$ to be in certain families of distributions (e.g. exponential family)?